# Provide user ID and password to sp-rest-proxy react app dynamically and run the proxy with the credentials

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, react, reactjs

I finally found the way to connect to SharePoint 2013 on-prem environment from an external react app. I made use of the sp-rest-proxy (https://github.com/koltyakov/sp-rest-proxy).

While deploying the app in build mode, it asked for my credentials and once provided the details are saved to my proxy.json file. Now I want enable this app so that it  captures the user ID and password from a form and then run the proxy. Basically I want to enable the app in such a way that it takes the user credentials and then run the proxy. Please guide me.